# How to add a youtube external unmute sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube

I am trying to put a button for unmute sound but having trouble executing it. My original plan was to do a toggle sound but I am looking to make the sound on work first

```js
 
   
    
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '600',
          width: '100%',
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
          videoId: 'W83b4HoPdFo',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
      }
  
  
  
       $('#mutevideo').on('click', function(){
                player.unmute();        
       
        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<a href="#" id="mutevideo">Sound On</a>
```

Comment: player.unmute(); - not sure if it will fix the issue, but the actual method is camel case I believe, i.e. player.unMute();

Comment: thanks manage to fix the issue. I had to paste the script after the html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
 player.unMute();
```

instead of

```
 player.unmute();
```